# Multiples values in same field in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to update "markes_category_in" with multiples values, for example "9" and "3".

```
UPDATE  `rx000437_info`.`markers`
SET  `markers_category_id` =  '9 , 3'
WHERE  `markers`.`markers_id` =25;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Its a bad pratice, fields must contain ONE value.
http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php

Comment: but... works? i dont want to duplicate the marker...

Comment: Ok, what are you going to do when you need to remove `marker_category_id` 9?

Comment: I dont go to delete never.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to restructure your database. Having multiple values in one field is bad practice, unless you really, really need to have a de-normalized table.

Something like this will perform better:

**Markers**

```
markersID  |  otherField
-----------|------------------
25         |
26         |
```

**MarkersCategories**

```
markersID  |  markersCategoryID
-----------|------------------
25         |  9
25         |  3
26         |  10
26         |  15
26         |  18
```

You can do multiple inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO MarkersCategories (markersID,markersCategoryID) VALUES (25,31),(25,32);
```

**UPDATE**

If you really just want to have a comma separated list and need to add a value to the end of the list, try:

```
UPDATE markers
SET markers_category_id = CONCAT(markers_category_id, ', 9')
WHERE markers_id = 25;
```

[See sqlFIDDLE demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34d0c/1)

Comment: Ok, what are you going to do when you need to remove `marker_category_id` 9? Tell me you have a quicker method than to use `DELETE FROM MarkersCategories WHERE markersCategoryID = 9`?

Comment: Making a road out of cardboard works, but it's considered bad practice because it wouldn't last very long and has no grip.

Comment: I dont want to duplicate the register. I just to add 2 diferents categories to my place: NIKE (shoes, tshirt). The DB is not mine. I try to do this. Sory for my english, im from argentina.

Comment: something like this INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column_name`) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)

Comment: @user1706064, no, that will add multiple rows.